# Convert url to image

Tags: ios, xcode, image, url, download

still learning programming and have a question.

im trying to download image from url and put it in cells, ive successfully done it with text but not with images.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"searchCell", for: indexPath)
    as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.titleField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].caption
    cell.descriptionField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].description
    cell.tagsField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].tags
    let photoUrl = posts[indexPath.row].photoUrl
    cell.SearchImage.image = ...
```

//url is stored in photoUrl

```
    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pod to make it easy

use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

then use it like this :

```
import SDWebImage

cell.SearchImage.sd_setImage(with: photoUrl, placeholderImage: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you, having problem with install, i followed the guide and all looked right but when i import webimage it says it doesnt exist.. even thought its in the podfile below.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this [third party library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher).

Kingfisher handles everything for you.

> A lightweight, pure-Swift library for downloading and caching images from the web.

If you don't know how to install it, have a look at [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), it's pretty straightforward.

Anyway, here is the only line of code needed to set an image from your URL with Kingfisher :

```
cell.SearchImage.kf.setImage(with: photoUrl)
```

By the way, you should follow the Swift convention described here in order to make your code easier to read and "universal".

Have a look : [Naming Convention](https://www.mobomo.com/2017/03/naming-conventions-for-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

On `swift3` You can use  `Alamofire` (https://cocoapods.org/) for that.

**Step 1:**

Integrate using pods.

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'

pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
```

**Step 2:**

```
import AlamofireImage

import Alamofire
```

**Step 3:**

```
Alamofire.request("https:// YOUR URL").responseImage { response in

if let image = response.result.value {
    print("image downloaded: \(image)")
self.myImageview.image = image
}
}
```

Or you can try this -

```
let url = URL(string: "https:// YOUR URL")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async() 
    {    
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: hate to seem so stupid, but ive legit tried all options from all answers and still doesnt work, the pods install but cant be imported, ive done pod installs before and they worked fine..

Comment: Just write import Alamafire under the import UIKit . Then press cmd+ shift+B. same for the AlamofireImage. ok. No error will be shown after that. try it

Comment: Didnt work :/
error: Cannot load underlying module for 'Alamofire'

Comment: Imports are case sensitive. are u using AlamFIre Or Alamofire ?

Comment: apparently product -> clean worked tho

Comment: Give me the full error

Comment: try - "cmd + k" and " shift + alt + cmd + k" then "cmd + shift + B" . let me know what happened.